# How to get only div text not span text using xpath

Tags: xpath, css-selectors

I am trying to get only order numbers like "190795". check the image [image]

What i have tried

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="sc-kafWEX ihwrOP"]//div/div/div[3]').text
```

But it will return span text such as "Order number:190795" like this.

I want only "190795"

This is my HTMl code
[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots where you could post code (possibly reduced to the content that is of interest).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a **text node**, you can not write an `XPath (v1.0)` for that, and Selenium make use of `XPath v1.0` , so you will have to be dependent on binding language.

Try this:

```
org_text = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="sc-kafWEX ihwrOP"]//div/div/div[3]').text
desired_text = org_text.split(':')[1]
print(desired_text)
```

Comment: You *can* write this with XPath 1.0: `//div[@class="sc-kafWEX ihwrOP"]//div/div/div[3]/text()[not(normalize-space()="")]`

Comment: @ThomasW: Selenium won't parse `text()` that you've written in the xpath.